# CDF and PDF for cartesian coordinates of disk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A random point 'M' is picked within the unit radius disk with center at origin. X and Y represent the cartesian coordinates and are random variables. What is the cumulative distribution function for these coordinates?

Other random variables are R and θ representing polar coordinates.

I have calculated CDF for polar coordinates as follows:

F<sub>R</sub>(r)=r<sup>2</sup>

F<sub>θ</sub>(θ)= θ/(2*pi)

Am I correct?

Also are these random variables independent of each other?

Comment: Do you mean "circle" or do you mean "disc"?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant disk. I will update it as well. Thanks.